# Adding image to Flutter

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter

this is my first time using Flutter and when I tried to add image it didn't quite work.
First I tried adding Image to child:Container via Image.assets('assets/lpp_bezpozadine.png') - didnt work
Then I tried making a separate method:

```
class LppImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AssetImage assetImage = AssetImage('assets/lpp_bezpozadine.png');
    Image image = Image(image: assetImage);
    return Container(
      child: image,
    );
  }
}
```

From which I tried to call children:  - but it said that I can't use children??

I have added the picture to pubspec.yaml as follow:

```
assets:
    - assets/lpp_bezpozadine.png
```

So if anyone could help me solve this, because I'm just starting at flutter. Thanks in advcance this is my code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const darkBlueColor = const Color(0xff131f40);
    const lightBlueColor = const Color(0xff445c9e);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                darkBlueColor,
                lightBlueColor,
              ],
              stops: [0.5, 1],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.2),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1, 1),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error log when I try to add children it says that convert it to child:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const darkBlueColor = const Color(0xff131f40);
    const lightBlueColor = const Color(0xff445c9e);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
       children: <Widget>[
          LppImage(),
        ],
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                darkBlueColor,
                lightBlueColor,
              ],
              stops: [0.5, 1],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.2),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1, 1),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it able to find the image? If you could post the specific error log that would be nice

Comment: @Stijn2210 ok I'll add it

Comment: I dont think you add the error log.

Comment: Yeah you didn't add the error log, but I did spot a mistake so i edited my answer based on that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if flutter is able to find the image because there's no error logs, but this is the correct way to use an asset image:

```dart
class LppImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Image.asset('assets/lpp_bezpozadine.png'),
    );
  }
}
```

Next to that, I see you're trying to use `Center` with `children`. `Center` only takes on `child`. So this is how you would use it:

```dart
Center(
  child: LppImage(),
),
```

If you want to use multiple children you should consider a `Column` so you can do this:

```dart
Column(
   children: [
      Center(
         child: LppImage(),
      ),
      Container(),
   ],
),
```

Comment: Ok I did it with column but now my background is gone, what should I do?

Comment: Set LppImage as the child of your container with your container with decoration and gradient

Comment: It worked partialy, now it has background but its cropped unlike before where the background was on whole screen as separate unit compared to image

Comment: Well that’s a different question. The image problem is solved now tho right?

Comment: Well yes but not rly, its like saying I fixed your engine of the car but your air conditioner is now not working. So now I have image but no background, background but no image or image with background only attached to it

Comment: If you want that problem solved ask a new question. Not discussing answers for different problems in the comments or expanding my answer based on that. Your initial question was that your image wasn’t loading/working and you’re saying that it is now

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a full app restart? some times hot reloaded does not see assets.

Comment: So from doc: Center({Key? key, double? widthFactor, double? heightFactor, Widget? child}) ;

Center Widget does not have children. i think you need to use a Column
and add to children: LppImage(), Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(..... )) etc